# Automatic deploy with cpanel Git™ Version Control not working

Tags: cpanel, git

I am trying to automatically deploy code to a shared hosting account, using the Git™ Version Control feature of CPANEL.

I can see from the history of the remote repository, that my code does reach the remote. and I can see the message generated by the post-receive hook of the remote repository.

It says,

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 302 bytes | 302.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Recieved update on checked-out branch, queueing deployment.
remote: --- 
remote: apiversion: 3
remote: func: create
remote: module: VersionControlDeployment
remote: result: 
remote:   data: ~
remote:   errors: ~
remote:   messages: ~
remote:   metadata: {}
remote: 
remote:   status: 1
remote:   warnings: ~
To ssh://my-domain.com/home/my-username/cicd
   7e20639..8ebdfb5  HEAD -> master
```

However, the deployment of files is not happening to the desired location.

**Contents of my .cpanel.yml file are as below**

```
---
deployment:
 tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/my-username/public_html/cicd.my-domain.com/
    - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
```

**Contents of my post receive hook are**

```
#!/bin/sh

# post-receive                                       Copyright 2018 cPanel, Inc.
#                                                           All rights reserved.
# copyright@cpanel.net                                         http://cpanel.net
# This code is subject to the cPanel license. Unauthorized copying is prohibited

branch=$(/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git branch | awk '$1 == "*"{print $2}')
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  if [ "x$ref" == "xrefs/heads/$branch" ]
  then
    echo "Recieved update on checked-out branch, queueing deployment."
    (cd .. ; /usr/bin/uapi VersionControlDeployment create repository_root=$PWD)
  fi
done < /dev/stdin
```

Cpanel **[Documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/UAPI+Functions+-+VersionControlDeployment%3A%3Acreate)** , says the "create" function will have log in the following location

**~/.cpanel/logs/vc_TIMESTAMP_git_deploy.log**

but there is no logs/ folder in there.maybe i cant see it because its a shared hosting.

**I updated the receive.denyCurrentBranch config item**

Updated the git config settings **receive.denyCurrentBranch** of the remote branch from **updateInstead** to **false**. Because otherwise I was getting the following error while pushing.

```
fatal: bad config value for 'receive.denycurrentbranch' in ./config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If it will help, my GIT remote version is **2.19.1**

Answer (score 2):

I've found if there are any untracked files in the repo directory the commands will not fire and you get the result you are seeing.

You can tell they did not fire because `data: ~` instead of a list of log files.

Here is how to solve it:

1. Go to your repo directory, in this case `ssh://my-domain.com/home/my-username/cicd`.
2. Run `git status` to list any untracked files.
3. Delete or commit any untracked files.
4. Try again.